# twisted websockets import error

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, importerror

I'm trying to get WebSocket working in Python with Twisted using this example: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/export/29073/branches/websocket-4173-2/doc/web/howto/websocket.xhtml. Unfortunately, I'm running into an ImportError. I'm not sure what to do here. I've installed/uninstalled Twisted several times using several methods (from source, from pip, and from Ubuntu repo), and this still pops up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "server.py", line 2, in <module>
from twisted.web.websocket import WebSocketHandler, WebSocketSite
ImportError: No module named websocket
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're linking to an example HOWTO from the `websocket-4173-2` branch. Obviously, that branch contains WebSockets code. On the other hand, Twisted trunk or any released versions do not.

Read http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4173 for more details on how it's progressing. To work with the development code, you could just checkout the aforementioned branch with svn.

Comment: Ah...I see. Can't believe I didn't notice that! Thank you.